# how position plane in sphere papervision3d as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, papervision3d

**How position plane in sphere papervision3d as3 ?**

I have a problème , how position a plane in surface of sphere.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example [over here](http://www.dehash.com/sphereoutline/).